# Semihosting (supervisory call)

Tags: debugging, arm

`.text` section of disassemble code

```
__exit:
 0x0: 0xe59f1008 LDR R1, [PC, #0x8] ; [0x10] 0x20026 (131110)
 0x4: 0xe3a00018 MOV R0, #24 ; 0x18
 0x8: 0xef123456 SVC #0x123456
 0xc: 0xeafffffb B __exit
```

I am calling the `exit()` function in my main function. The above assembly code is appearing in a disassemble window .

How to execute the `B __exit` instruction?

My source code is `main(){ __exit(arg); }`

This is a [related question to arm semihosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503680/use-of-arm-semihosting/23291687?noredirect=1#comment35654081_23291687).

Answer (score 2):

The `b __exit` only loops you back to the beginning of the function.

In an embedded environment, there is typically no program exit; rather, you either go into an endless loop or restart from the beginning.

This fragment goes into an endless loop, invoking the semihosting SVC for an explicit breakpoint, thus bringing you into the debugger. Restarting from there will execute the branch and reexecute the code leading to the breakpoint.

Comment: after B __exit call following dissassembly routine appears         DC32 131110 can some one help how i will get all these statement covered c source code

Comment: The following code is not used; the `b` instruction makes sure of that.

Comment: It is quite possible that there is no C code, or if there is, it is going to be a macro resolving to an `asm` statement.

Comment: Richer can u explain in detail about this "Restarting from there will execute the branch and reexecute the code leading to the breakpoint".

Comment: When that code is executed, the semihosting call will break into the debugger, with the "next instruction" pointing at `b __exit`, and the device stopped. Restarting the device will execute the branch instruction, and re-execute the semihosting call.

Comment: Richer "Restartin the device".??is it posiblle in simulator without connecting a device(Board)

Comment: The simulator should behave identically to the device.

Comment: So i need to execute the script in release mode then it will break into debugger mode.and how to do the restart of device in debugger mode.